# My keyboard won't print characters other than lower case Latin alphabet

Tags: 14.04

I'm not sure how this happened, but other than Latin lower case alphabet characters, all the letters and numbers on my keyboard provide odd characters.

For example:
abcdefɡhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

With shift:
ɑβçðɛɱɣɥɪɲɬʎɯŋɔʋɒʁʃθʊʌʍχʏʒ

And one throuɡh equal siɡn on number row:
ɨøɜɾɫɐɤɵœ̥-̩

Answer (score 1):

It was team viewer.  It apparently ignores all keyboard settings on the remote host.  Even though the client computer was working fine.  Even typing in the partner ID box gave those weird characters.  Restarting it fixed the issue.  Strange as there are no keyboard input settings anywhere in team viewer that I could actually find.